# how to restore ubuntu 22.04 graphics?

Tags: graphics, 22.04, restore

I am using ubuntu 22.10

I was installing something when I ran this command by mistake:

‍‍‍‍‍‍`sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev`

The system was deleting files when my laptop graphic was deleted and I entered the terminal. I have tried to reinstall these many times, but I have not been able to get into the graphics section. I will be happy if you help me

‍‍‍

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: If that is really the command you entered, then apt gave you a complete list of all proposed changes and offered you the opportunity to review that proposal and refuse. You have learned an important lesson: Read that output before agreeing.

Comment: Wow! It worked :) If it didn't work I would have had to migrate from Linux to Window forever