# How to restore ubuntu graphics after deleting python?

Tags: apt, graphics, python, 23.04

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 right now and I've made a similar mistake before

[Q](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1480875/)

I was doing something that told me to remove and reinstall python3.11 and I ran this command

`sudo apt remove python3.11`

It was during the execution of the command that my Ubuntu graphics disappeared and only the black screen of the terminal could be seen
I tried to reinstall Python3.11 but I got this problem:

`` E: Package `python3.11` has no installation candidate ``

And when I tried to install Ubuntu Desktop (the way I installed it before and it worked), it gave me this error:

`E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.`

I really don't know what to do!!
Help me please

Comment: What about `sudo apt install python3`?

Comment: Never remove python (or change the default python version) in Ubuntu. It is like removing one's vital organs. You cannot easily reverse that. If reinstalling `python3` or `ubuntu-desktop` does not work, *you will have to reinstall Ubuntu*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not aware that I should not delete Python. Installing Python 3 works the same as 3.11.

Comment: If that did not work, you will have to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. One question, what should I do so that all my applications, photos and files are available when I install the new version of Ubuntu?

Comment: For photos and files: Save them on an different partition than where Ubuntu is installed. Then they will not be overwritten during the reinstallation. You can do that even from the live USB before you reinstall. For applications, I do the following. I maintain a script containing name of all the applications I need. `sudo apt install app1 app2 app3 ...`. I save this script in a cloud storage service, and run this on a new installation. I keep this script updated if I need a new application.